# Passing rendered html to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jstl, el

I have some html code rendered on the server side. This is passed to a jsp which renders a javascript-call with this html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.${param.popup_return}("${helpId}", "${content}");
</script>
```

content is like

```
"
This is a <p class="xyz">test</p>
"
```

My problem is that - according to the quotes in 'content' - the javascript-call is wrong as it is rendered to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.${param.popup_return}("ybc", "This is a <p class="xyz">test</p>");
</script>
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this (besides manually replacing all quotes)?

Comment: I fear escaping quotes is going to feature in any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON encoder to create the encoded strings.

But you'll also have to ensure that the output doesn't contain the sequence `</` in string literals, which is invalid in a `<script>` block (`</script` is the version that will also break browsers).

Many JSON encoders either by default or optionally will encode to `<\/` or `\u003C/` to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
<div id="result" style="display:none">
  ${content}
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.parent.${param.popup_return}("${helpId}", dojo.byId("result").innerHTML);
</script>
```

This seems to work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using JSTL here (you originally tagged the question with only JSTL). You are using EL in template text. It get printed plain as-is. You'd like to use JSTL core [`<c:out>`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) to escape [predefined XML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) (which also works for HTML in this particular case, quotes is among the escaped XML entities).

```
window.parent.${param.popup_return}("<c:out value="${helpId}" />", "<c:out value="${content}" />");
```

An alternative (if you hate that the JSP syntax highlighter or validator bugs/jerks about nested tags/quotes) is the JSTL function [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html):

```
window.parent.${param.popup_return}("${fn:escapeXml(helpId)}", "${fn:escapeXml(content)}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using single quotes instead of double quotes? i.e. changing `"${content}"` to `'${content}'`